# Can't use :last-child when importing component

Tags: angular, css-selectors, angular-components

I've created a component app-day-part and importing it in a parent component

```
<app-day-part
            *ngFor="let part of dayParts; let lastItem = last"
            [partBlock]="part"
        ></app-day-part>
```

so i'm using *ngFor for looping the content of my component because everything what's changing is a data which i'm changing by using a method

```
<div class="item-weather-page">
  <h3 class="item-weather-page__title big-text">{{ partBlock.daypart }}</h3>
  <div class="item-weather-page__columns">
    <div class="item-weather-page__column">
      <p class="item-weather-page__time">{{ partBlock.time[0] }}</p>
      <img [src]="" alt="" class="item-weather-page__img" />
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">
        {{ currentFirstHour?.temp_c | number : "1.0-0" }}°
      </p>
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">
        {{ currentFirstHour?.feelslike_c | number : "1.0-0" }}°
      </p>
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">
        {{ currentFirstHour?.pressure_mb }}
      </p>
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">{{ currentFirstHour?.humidity }}</p>
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">{{ currentFirstHour?.wind_kph }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-weather-page__column">
      <p class="item-weather-page__time">{{ partBlock.time[1] }}</p>
      <img [src]="" alt="" class="item-weather-page__img" />
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">
        {{ currentSecondHour?.temp_c | number : "1.0-0" }}°
      </p>
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">
        {{ currentSecondHour?.feelslike_c | number : "1.0-0" }}°
      </p>
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">
        {{ currentSecondHour?.pressure_mb }}
      </p>
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">{{ currentSecondHour?.humidity }}</p>
      <p class="item-weather-page__parms">{{ currentSecondHour?.wind_kph }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i'm using border-right on item-weather-page and it works, but when i'm trying to use :last-child it doesnt work

```
.item-weather-page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  &:last-child{
    border-right: none;
  }

  &__columns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 50px;
  }

  &__column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 16px;
  }

  &__title {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  &__time {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
  }

  &__img {
    width: 50px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  &__parms {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: Open Sans;
  }
}
```

Please help to fix this problem